# How to show the saved data of 3 forms in my template in Django?

Tags: python, django

let's say I have a form_1 (PresupuestosClientesForm) and form_2 (PresupuestosVehiculosForm), those forms store information and they are in different html pages. I would like to have a view that presents the information saved in forms 1 and 2 in the same template. How can I do that?

With my view i am only retrieving the form but not the saved data of the form

****view.py****

```
def step7(request):

    presupuestosclientesform=PresupuestosClientesForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)
    presupuestosvehiculosform=PresupuestosVehiculosForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
    if presupuestosclientesform.is_valid():
        presupuestosclientesform.save()
        return redirect('presupuestos:index')
    return render(request,'Presupuestos/new-estimate-7-preview.html',{'presupuestosclientesform':presupuestosclientesform,'presupuestosvehiculosform':presupuestosvehiculosform})
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="text-muted">
    <p class="mb-1"><i class="uil uil-envelope-alt me-1"></i> 
       {{presupuestosclientesform}}
    </p> 
</div>
<div class="text-muted">
    <p class="mb-1"><i class="uil uil-envelope-alt me-1"></i> 
       {{presupuestosvehiculosform}}
    </p> 
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add the whole code. And so you want to show the data using forms in templates or you want to save data of the 2 forms coming from a single template?

Comment: hello! what I want is to show the saved data, as I have it, it only shows the inputs to save info but not to show what has already been saved.

Comment: Ok, that is possible but you need to prepopulate the forms before sending them to the front-end.

Comment: yes, in fact I have these forms in other html and they save the information. But I have no idea how to retrieve that data from those forms and display it in another html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to use Django forms for editing data, we first need to prepopulate those forms with the data that we want to edit then pass them as dictionaries to Django templates. You can do that in this way...

```
def step7(request):
    instance1 = get_object_or_404(ModelName, id=value) #Fetch data that you want to change from the model according to your needs.
    instance2 = get_object_or_404(ModelName, id=value) #Fetch data that you want to change from the model according to your needs.
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form1 = AddForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('url_name')    
    
    else:
      first_form = AddForm(instance=instance1) #Here is the change
      second_form = AddForm(instance=instance2) #Here is the change
      return render(request, 'TemplateName', {'first_form ': first_form, 'second_form': second_form  })
```

Comment: amazing!!!! it works. You have recovered the information!!!! Just one more question, what happens is that it recovers the information but in input mode that can be edited, how can I do it so that it is not edited and the data is seen without the input

Comment: Let's say you want to change the data you saved in model1 and that data has a primary key(pk), by default that pk has field name id in Django. To get that saved data we fetch that data from our Django model and if we will use the pk for this like instance = model1.objects.get(field_name=pk_value). Now we have that data we want to change in an instance variable and we will assign that variable to our forms as I did in the answer

Comment: Then you don't need to use forms if you just want to display data. For that, you can fetch the information like this instance = model1.objects.get(field_name=pk_value) then pass the instance to the template and display them using this tag inside your HTML tags {{instance.model_field_name}}

Comment: Just one last question, here: (field_name=pk_value) , in pk_value is a number placed? I put id=id and name=pk_value but it doesn't work for me (name is inside my client model). Thank you for your patience with me

Comment: So you want to fetch the client with the name?

Comment: no, it would be more for the id.

Comment: You need to put integer value if you are getting data by id or primary key and if you are fetching data by client name you need to add string data. The data type depends on the type of field you are using to fetch the data.